# How to save multiple checkboxes in one string

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm looking for some help to put values from multiple checkboxes together in one string seperated by ','

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitKon'])) {   
$checkBox = $_POST[$holdID[$i]];

<?php
    $i=1;
    $virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  `hold` INNER JOIN  `virksomheder` ON hold.virkID = virksomheder.virkID
    WHERE hold.virkID = '$virksomhedsID' ORDER BY  `holdNavn` ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
    echo '<label for="check' . $row['holdNavn'] . '">' . $row['holdNavn'] . '</label>&nbsp;';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="' . $row['holdID'] . '" name="' . $row['holdID'] . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;';                         
    $i++;       
?>
```

Can anyone help with this?
Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that your code is not correct? I'm just asking because you have php code outside <?php, and you use $i before asigning a value to it.

Comment: its just cut outs where the code is relevant for the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkboxes names should be all set to for example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="{$row['holdID']}" />
```

And then values of checked boxes should be in `$_POST['check']` so I think you should try (on the page where you recieve your `$_POST`)

```
implode(',',$_POST['check']);
 //or something like
$checkstring="";
foreach($_POST['check'] as $checkboxes) {
  $checkstring.= $checkboxes .",";
}
echo rtrim($checkstring);
```

Comment: thanks, but where do I put the implode?

Comment: On the page where you send your form. If it is the same page than probbably like if (isset($_POST['submitKon'])) {   
$checkBox = implode(',',$_POST['holdmyvalues']);

Comment: okay and the .. $checkstring="";
foreach($_POST['holdmyvalues'] as $checkboxes) {
  $checkstring.= $checkboxes .",";
}
echo rtrim($checkstring); where do i put this?

Comment: try with implode() only and you should get what you are looking for

Comment: yes but inside or outside the while?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? Outside. Whats the point of implode() in while loop ? Maybe if you explain exactly what are you trying to achieve we can help you better, because it is kind of vague to me

Comment: no matter if I put it inside or outside I get a warning:
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21419/discussion-between-vodich-and-m-nielsen)

Comment: Im trying to tie teams to a competition, and so I would like to sample all the teams ID from the checkboxes in a string seperated with a ','
so my row in the table would be something like competition: running, teams: a, b, c

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. Your `$i` variable is never being used, was this intentional?

Also you were missing the closing `}` at the end of the while statement.

In your label you wrote `for=` did you mean `id=`?

This should iterate through the results and print a label and a checkbox for each result. i added the "," before the final two `&nbsp;`

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    echo "<label id='check".$row['holdNavn']."'>".$row['holdNavn']."</label>&nbsp;
          <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' id='".$row['holdID']."' name='".$row['holdID']."'>,&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have made the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't write anything..

Comment: Odd... What is your browser you are using? and PC, MAC, Linux? Also try the suggestion by @vodich above, not sure if that will work either, but could be worth a shot.